# Access token is not authorized with this scope relationship

Tags: android, instagram, instagram-api

I am appending scope to auth url like this >>>  scope=likes+comments+relationships+basic";

But while logging in, it is not asking user for relationship permission, only showing "this app can acess your photos".

Inside the application whenever i am follwoing or unfollwing any user by hitting

```
String url="https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/"+userid+"/relationship/?access_token="+MainSingleTon.accesstoken;
            // key and value pair
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action","unfollow"));


            JSONObject json=jParser.getJSONFromUrlByPost(url, nameValuePair);
```

i am getting json response as

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"OAuthPermissionsException","error_message":"This request requires scope=relationships, but this access token is not authorized with this scope. The user must re-authorize your application with scope=relationships to be granted write permissions.","code":400}}
```

Comment: you should read the api's documentation, and check which token you need to append to the request

Comment: @Blackbelt it is same accesstoken which i am getting after login

Comment: While trying with another user id , i am getting this below response.



{"meta":{"error_type":"APIError","error_message":"This client ID is not permitted to POST relationships actions. For more info, please refer refer to our developer site at http:\/\/instagram.com\/developer\/endpoints\/relationships.","code":400}}

--------------I have already requested permission for this scope under developer.instgram.com . 

No response from there side, its been 10 days has been  passed.

Answer (score 3):

This is a post request. To make post request to InstagramAPI you need to submit your application details and company details to Instagram for review. Maybe other relationship endpoints will work fine without submitting your app. For more details visit the following link https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/relationships/#post_relationship